# How do I access a string from a class

Tags: java, class, public

how would I access the entered value "Username" from another class? inside the package
I'm having trouble coding that. Should I declare some variable public?
I declared the Username public, but I get errors

this is my code:

```
package login;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Login() {
        initComponents0();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents0() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        uname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        login = new javax.swing.JButton();
        reset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pwd = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Login Pane");
        jLabel2.setText("User Name:");
        jLabel3.setText("Password:");
        login.setText("Login");
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String un = uname.getText();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String pw = pwd.getText();
        try{
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
                try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream)) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                boolean registered = false;
                boolean registered0 = false;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                String values[] = strLine.split("\\|");
                if ((strLine.startsWith(un))&&(pw.equals(values[1]))){
                registered = true;
                break;
                }
                if ((strLine.startsWith(un))&&(!pw.equals(values[1]))){
                registered0 = true;
                break;
                }
                }
                if(registered){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello: "+un ,"Registration",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                  File file = new File("temp.dat");
                try {
                                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false)) {
                                String data0 = un;
                                writer.write(data0);
                                }} 
                catch (IOException | HeadlessException z) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                                }
                }
                else if(registered0){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It seems you entered a wrong password! \n Please try again " ,"Admin",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                else
                {
                int sel = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"It seems that you haven't registered yet? \n Launch Registration Pane?","Admin",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (sel == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                new Register().setVisible(true);
                }});}

                }}}
                catch (  IOException | HeadlessException ez){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"A null file was created in order to \n avoid File Catch errors","Admin",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                File file = new File("data.dat");
                try {
                                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
                                String data0 = "null";
                                String data1 = "null";
                                writer.write(data0+" | "+data1+"\n");
                                }} 
                catch (IOException | HeadlessException z) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                                }
                }
        }});
        reset.setText("Reset Field");
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                uname.setText("");
                                pwd.setText("");
                                } 
                                });
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(uname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 300, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(reset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(pwd))))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(uname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(pwd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(login)
                    .addComponent(reset))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JButton login;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField pwd;
    private javax.swing.JButton reset;
    private javax.swing.JTextField uname;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

edited

```
package login;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private String username,password;
public String getUsername() {
return username;
}
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

    public Login() {
        initComponents0();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents0() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        uname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        login = new javax.swing.JButton();
        reset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pwd = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Login Pane");
        jLabel2.setText("User Name:");
        jLabel3.setText("Password:");
        login.setText("Login");
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String un = uname.getText();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String pw = pwd.getText();
        username = un;
        password = pw;

        try{
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
                try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream)) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                boolean registered = false;
                boolean registered0 = false;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                String values[] = strLine.split("\\|");
                if ((strLine.startsWith(un))&&(pw.equals(values[1]))){
                registered = true;
                break;
                }
                if ((strLine.startsWith(un))&&(!pw.equals(values[1]))){
                registered0 = true;

                break;
                }
                }
                if(registered){

                  username = un;
                  password = pw;

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello: "+un ,"Registration",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                  File file = new File("temp.dat");
                try {
                                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false)) {
                                String data0 = un;
                                writer.write(data0);
                                }} 
                catch (IOException | HeadlessException z) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                                }
                }
                else if(registered0){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It seems you entered a wrong password! \n Please try again " ,"Admin",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                else
                {
                int sel = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"It seems that you haven't registered yet? \n Launch Registration Pane?","Admin",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (sel == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                new Register().setVisible(true);
                }});}

                }}}
                catch (  IOException | HeadlessException ez){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"A null file was created in order to \n avoid File Catch errors","Admin",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                File file = new File("data.dat");
                try {
                                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
                                String data0 = "null";
                                String data1 = "null";
                                writer.write(data0+" | "+data1+"\n");
                                }} 
                catch (IOException | HeadlessException z) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                                }
                }
        }});
        reset.setText("Reset Field");
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                uname.setText("");
                                pwd.setText("");
                                } 
                                });
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(uname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 300, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(reset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(pwd))))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(uname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(pwd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(login)
                    .addComponent(reset))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    /*
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JButton login;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField pwd;
    private javax.swing.JButton reset;
    private javax.swing.JTextField uname;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `private` global non-static fields to hold the `username` and `password` fields, when you accept the input assign the values to your global `username` and `password` variables. Then have getter method(s) which are `public` and return the `username` and `password` for that instance.

something like:

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private String username,password;//assign private global fields for the instance

//the variables are assigned when you accept user input

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}
}
```

you'd then do something like:

```
Login lg=new Login();//create new instance to gain access to getter methods
//wait for it to return or until user has enetered the credentials
System.out.println(lg.getUsername());
System.out.println(lg.getPassword());
```

Comment: What do you mean by **global**?

Comment: @f_puras global, as in variables which can be accessed throughout the containing class

Comment: Ok, of course - as opposed to local vars. Didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Where do I put this? In a new class?

`Login lg=new Login();//create new instance to gain access to getter methods`
`//wait for it to return or until user has enetered the credentials`
`System.out.println(lg.getUsername());`
`System.out.println(lg.getPassword());`

when I run that It prints null even if I entered a value in the field

Comment: @JFetz2191 because how does it know when the values are entered ? you'd need some sort of boolean which is false until the username and password is assgined then only print when the input has been taken

Comment: @David Kroukamp There's a "if" in my code, can I put your code there?

Comment: @JFetz2191 yes you can as long as it does what you need

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I put the public
`String getUsername() {
return username;
}`
`public String getPassword() {
return password;
}`
}`

inside the If {} and it give me Illegal Start of expression error

Comment: @JFetz2191 you cant have methods in an if statement, you should place the methods in your login class, and place calls to the methods in the if statements like the system.out.println i had

Comment: Look at my code, putting this 

`username = un;`
`password = pw;`

in if(registered){}

would actually assign a value to getUsername() and getPassword()? can I accessed it to the other class, I tried but the second code you make writes null.. even if I pressed login button from my login.java.. I put your second code to another .java @DavidKroukamp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15862/discussion-between-jfetz2191-and-david-kroukamp)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have public setters and getters for you private variables in order to call or edit your private variables from out side of your class. This is called as `encapsulation` one of the important concept of `OOP`. You may want to google for it know more.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable in global scope and also declare those variables with `Public` access specifier. Or

use getter method for `Private` declared variables .And make those getter method `Public`.